# Pycharm debugger getting error when break point is kept

Tags: django, python-3.x, debugging, pycharm

**In one of my project, I am using Django==2.1.5 on Pycharm IDE 2019.2 and I'm facing this error while debugging

1) I have tried to fix this problem by removing the .idea folder and reconfigured, the problem was not solved.

2) I have tried uninstalling the python and re-installed, the problem was not solved.

3) I have updated the Pycharm and tried, the problem was not solved the same error is throwing.**

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <_pydev_bundle.pydev_monkey._NewThreadStartupWithTrace object at 0x0576E6F0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_constants.py", line 328, in get_current_thread_id
AttributeError: '_DummyThread' object has no attribute '__pydevd_id__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SystemError: ..\Objects\codeobject.c:851: bad argument to internal function

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_monkey.py", line 718, in __call__
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_constants.py", line 335, in get_current_thread_id
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_constants.py", line 302, in _get_or_compute_thread_id_with_lock
SystemError: <built-in method __enter__ of _thread.lock object at 0x0144ADA0> returned a result with an error set
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the short description you gave, I can only suppose that the issue **only** occurs when running the application in *debug* mode. If that is the case, please try setting the following environment variables inside your [*run*/*debug* configuration in PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html) and see if the issue still occurs:

```
PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON=NO
PYDEVD_USE_FRAME_EVAL=NO
```

**Note that this is a temporary fix** - you should further investigate the exact cause of the issue and other approaches to resolving it.

---

Also note that in the future, you should provide a little more details about the project configuration, where and when does the exception occur *(reproduction scenario)*, as well as other information that could make it easier to successfully identify the issue.